# 13" Laptop with anti-glare display

Tags: laptop, displays

In these days it is hard to find any laptop with an anti-glare display. Some ZenBooks have had them in 2016.

Does anybody have a recommendation für a 13" laptop with 8th-gen core-processor and anti-glare display?

Comment: It might be easier just to buy an anti-glare film and put that on a laptop that meets your specifications.

Comment: I hate these films :-(

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned ZenBooks. There is a SKU with an 8th gen i5 and an anti-glare screen.

**[ASUS ZenBook UX330UA-AH55](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075N1YHVK)**

Also the Dell XPS 13 9360 has such a configuration option. See here http://www.microcenter.com/product/487760/xps_13_9360_133_laptop_computer_-_silver. As well as the Lenovo 720 https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/yoga/700-series/Yoga-720-13/p/88YG7000827

Something not from the big brands is the [Sager NP3132](https://www.sagernotebook.com/Notebook-NP3132.html), pretty expansive but a lot of configuration options.